# Como enviar información obtenida de una fila de datatables al presionar un botón para un método en la clase Controller en laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

Lo que estoy haciendo es que una vez que el usuario seleccione la fila de la datatable que quiere modificar se activa el botón editar y que cuando este pinche en el botón se muestre el formulario de editar, pero no logro como enviar la información para el controller para que me muestre la vista correctamente.

```
            {
                className: 'btn-warning',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Edit',
                action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
                    var info = JSON.stringify(dt.row({
                        selected: true
                    }).data());
                    alert(info);
                "{{ route('gestionar.departamentos.edit,') }}"//y al lado de la coma iría la variable info que es la que tiene el array con la información
                },
                enabled: false

            },
```

obtengo bien la información que selecciona el usuario pero no se como pasarla en la ruta para el controller, no se si me explique bien soy nuevo gracias de ante mano.